# is the volatile map can be null after initial in java?

Tags: java, volatile

```
public class SipResponseCollection {

    private final static Logger LOGGER=Logger.getLogger(SipResponseCollection.class);
    private volatile Map<String, List<SipResponse>> map = new HashMap<String, List<SipResponse>>();

    public SipResponseCollection() {
    }

    public boolean contain(String callId, int statusCode) {
        List<SipResponse> list = map.get(callId);  //pop null exception in linux amd64 machine but right for windows machine. callId is not null.
        if(list==null)
            return false;
        for (SipResponse sipResponse : list) {
            if (sipResponse.getStatusCode() == statusCode)
                return true;
        }

        return false;
}
}
```

after new SipResponseCollection(), if the volatile map can be null?  I run on the different machine, one machine hint null exception. but after remove the keyword: volatile , all are ok. why?

ps: no any public method can set the map to null.

Comment: What is the code for the `getStatusCode()` method?

Answer (score 2):

No, it can't be `null`—unless you manage to *leak `this`* from the constructor. You don't seem to be doing that.

If you had shown us more code, such as the code which triggers the `NullPointerException`, there may be something more substantive to say about your problem.

Note that your field is not `final` so the possibility is still open that the field is nulled out from anywhere in your program.

Comment: no, there is no any method to set the map to null.but the issue always exist on one linux 64 machine.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that line can through - map can be null, get() can through an NPE. I offer a couple of theories, but they involve the real code not being the same as what you wrote.

- That's some other Map and not HashMap, or you have some weird degenerate HashMap which doesn't support null keys.

Map.get() can NPE on null keys, but the implementation of HashMap doesn't.  Are you running the same JVM implementation on both?   Seems like a stretch.  Do you know for sure callId is not null?

- You're calling contains() before the initializers are run.

Instance initializers occur after the constructor is done. If you:

- Call contains() in the constructor, or
- Make a call that leaks the object to something which calls contains()

The map won't be initialized yet, and will be null.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any problem through your description and code.

So as @Marko Topolnik mentioned :

#### Change your volatile map to final, and see what happens.